# Can we migrate private blockchain from one aws instance to another?

Tags: go-ethereum, aws

Right now, I am running my private blockchain on aws ec2(t2.medium) using geth. I am just curious that later on is it possible to upgrade that aws ec2(t2.medium) instance to aws ec2(t2.large) instance? If yes, then What steps I have to follow for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading the existing ec2(t2.medium) to ec2(t2.large) will in no way affect the migration of private blockchain as long as you ensure that following directories from t2.medium are moved to t2.large:

- geth
- keystore

Also, make sure to move the `history` file.

The directories `geth, keystore` must be located in a `directory` which was mentioned as a parameter to `--datadir` when launching the private network using geth.

And, yes, the RPC endpoint will change i.e. `--rpcaddr` and if you have specified a websocket endpoint that too will change i.e. `--wsaddr`

Thus, the steps would be moving `geth, keystore, history` from t2.medium to t2.large